# How to get sql time date variable print only date-part even though we are assigning date time object

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get T-SQL to print only date part from `datetime` object? I tried with convert of 101 format which doesn't work as it prints time as well.

This is the code I am talking about:

```
DECLARE @ReceivedDate DATETIME = GETDATE()

SET @ReceivedDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(RTRIM(@ReceivedDate) AS DATE), 101);
PRINT @ReceivedDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:  From question change.

To get just date, just do this:

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

OR

```
declare @ReceivedDate datetime=getdate() 

DECLARE @Dateonly AS VARCHAR(50)

SET @DateOnly = Cast(@ReceivedDate as Date)

PRINT @DateOnly
```

Original question's answer to get just time

You had a couple issues.
  1.  Your were doing wrong convert to get time.

2. You saved the convert back to a variable that was date/time so it will add the date back in.

You need to fix the convert and either create a new variable (like below) to put the results of the convert into or just print out the convert directly.

```
declare @ReceivedDate datetime=getdate() 

DECLARE @TimeOnly AS VARCHAR(50)

SET @TimeOnly = CONVERT(varchar(10),@ReceivedDate, 108); 

PRINT @TimeOnly
```

Comment: Updated my answer with solution to get just date at time.  Same error applies you are trying to cast just a date into a dateime variable.  you cant do that

Answer (score 1):

Use of the following according to the format you need:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 101);
Output: 07/16/2019

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 105);
Output: 16-07-2019

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 111);
Output: 2019/07/16
```

Answer (score 0):

you code is correct the problem is you are assigning it back to a datetime variable and printing the datetime variable which would definitely have time stamp. you should be assigning it to a string or to a date variable before printing

```
    declare @ReceivedDate datetime=getdate()
    SET @ReceivedDate = Convert(varchar(10),@ReceivedDate, 101);
    print @ReceivedDate
    print Convert(varchar(10),@ReceivedDate, 110);
```

output

```
    Jul 16 2019 12:00AM
    07-16-2019
```